# Python crawler verification picture

Tags: python, curl, web-crawler

I want to crawl a verification picture, and I've achieve it by using curl like this.

```
curl "https://www.ris.gov.tw/apply/captcha/image?CAPTCHA_KEY=71cc3b094e824446873038401ab8c303&time=1464968502855" -H "Referer: https://www.ris.gov.tw/id_card/" --insecure >> a.jpg
```

P.S (the `CAPTCHA_KEY` and `time` need to be created every time )

It worked fine and saved a verification picture into `a.jpg`.

Now I was trying to rewrite in python, here is what I've done.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from datetime import datetime
import shutil
import time
from IPython.display import Image
from random import randint

ori = requests.get("https://www.ris.gov.tw/id_card/")
soup = BeautifulSoup(ori.text)
key =  soup.select('#captchaKey')[0]["value"]
#Get CAPTCHA_KEY 
rs = requests.session()
url = "https://www.ris.gov.tw/apply/captcha/image?CAPTCHA_KEY=" + key
time =  str(int((time.time())*100)) + str(randint(0,9))
url += "&time=" + time
#Get time 

res = rs.get(url, headers={'referer': 'https://www.ris.gov.tw/id_card/'}, stream = True, verify =False)

f= open('check.jpg','wb')
shutil.copyfileobj(res.raw,f)
f.close()
Image('check.jpg')
```

I was stuck for a while and didn't know how to figure it out.

Comment: So, are you getting an error, or what?

Comment: It didn't get verification picture, and the `check.jpg` seems not a picture format, I can't open it.

Comment: If you need help finding out what goes wrong, you should provide a [mcve]

Comment: I knew that....but it's hard for me to decide what I need to provide now, cause as a beginner I was afraid of that I will post too less and miss some important part.  I will do my best to modify, thanks.

Comment: why did you use png in there?

Comment: Oh, I forget to modify it, thanks. But it still lead the same result.

Comment: @CodaChang Your check.png is actually a gzip compressed JPEG. Uncompress it to get the image.

Comment: yeah! Thanks  @David Cullen, I change it into jpg file, and it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These changes gave me the JPEG file:

```
res = rs.get(url, headers={'referer': 'https://www.ris.gov.tw/id_card/'})
with open('check.jpg', 'wb') as jpeg_file:
    jpeg_file.write(res.content)
```

The [content](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/api/#requests.Response.content) is the response as bytes which can be written directly to a file.